# How to have separate pages for username and password with django user login?

Tags: django, django-views

I have an extended django user model, and I want the user to first enter their username then be redirected to another page that asks for their password. Somewhat similar to how amazon handles user login.

Do I just use 2 separate views and pass the username as an input to the password view?
Second question, can this cause a security problem?

```
def usernameView(request):
    # get username and redirect to password

def passwordView(request, username):
    # get password if correct login
```

Comment: You could store the username in `request.session['username']` in the usernameView and then submit it as an invisible field on the passwordView.

Not sure if it's worth the hassle though, what's your reason for doing it this way?

Comment: I want to send a temporary password for one time login, this is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586943/send-password-on-user-registration-django-allauth

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to send a new password every time a user wants to login and not on sign up.